# Will I be able to contribute to Ubuntu in the future through other services in addition to PayPal?

Tags: community, canonical, contributing

Now on [Desktop Contribute Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions), I can donate only using PayPal. Will I be able to donate in the future, using, for example, VISA credit card?

Comment: I think Canonical should provide [Bitcoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin). That would be great.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE I would love that. Except that (speaking of Paypal) many payment providers don't allow you to purchase it so it is hard to get any. Unless you hook a bank account or pay double on eBay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We definitely will add other ways to contribute in the future, for this release we only had time to integrate one system and there was an existing mechanism that used to be in our /community section that used PayPal and had an account ready to go, so it was, by far easiest to just use that initially.

As other have mentioned, you can just use use a credit card on PayPal, you don't need to setup an account.

Comment: I (and others) reject PayPal on principle - but it is good to know that there will be other methods of payment. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed donate with your credit card with Paypal, so that might have been a bad example.

The ability to use Paypal gives you a range of options if you have a Paypal account, including credit from items that you sell (such as Ebay items) and even linked bank accounts.  It's one of the more secure ways to do business online because only Paypal gets to see your card or account details; it significantly reduces the risk.

If you are looking for other financial ways to support Ubuntu and Canonical, you might like to have a look at some of the great Ubuntu merchandise available:

https://shop.canonical.com/

Comment: What is if the user don't want to buy something?

Comment: I'm not use PayPal. Because I have had bad experiences associated with PayPal (I'm from Russia). I do not want to register with PayPal only to make a donation to Ubuntu. If there was support payments via VISA or MasterCard, I would have 1 minute to make a donation.

Comment: Sorry to hear you had trouble.  You don't need to login to make a payment, just select "don't have an account" down the bottom and you will be directed to the guest payment facility where you can make a one time payment.  Here in Australia we can get loadable debit cards which are perfect for on-line use.  http://auspost.com.au/personal/loadandgo-reloadable-prepaid-visa-card.html  Perhaps you have access to something similar if you are still worried about it.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE : Apparently Canonical have moved the donation page off the "get involved" donations page off their website and downloads from the main "get Ubuntu" site now direct you to a donations page.  Here it is: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts  Note that you can also use this to tell Canonical where the money is to be spent.